# Class members always as pointers for consistency?

Tags: c++

Consider this class.

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>

class A;
class B;

class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> m_a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> m_string1; // 1
    std::string m_string2; // 2
};
```

I always try to forward declare classes in header files. However, I won't do that for standard headers, forward declaring typedefs of template classes is just painful. Anyway, if I have the header available - should I prefer the first way or second way - `m_string1` or `m_string2`? I feel that if I mix pointers and value types then it looks inconsistent. Is it a good idea to make everything a pointer?

Comment: This question belongs on http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I think using pointers to every member might lead to extra space - pointers take 4 bytes in 32-bit and 8-bytes in 64-bit system. Simple data types are better stored as in value.

Comment: @cppcoder: it may be alignment makes short types to be stored into same long spaces ... hard to say when (and not) this is true.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` already holds a dynamic structure (so it is itself a pointer)

After all, If you consider a string an "opaque type" so opaque you even don't want to include its header, the same should be also for unique_ptr... but you must stop sooner or later, or you will end up with a class of plain pointers, with the big-5 (ctor, dtor, copy, assign, move, transfer) all redefined. But this is re-implementing smart pointers every time.

Consider also that breaking a class into too small dynamic "details" spreads objects aruond the memory, disallowing (or making more difficult) any processor optimization based on system caches.

If then you have some templates, the *pimpl* idiom becomes even useless: you have to expose your entire class as a header.

It seems to me you just went too deep into the application of this idiom.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this, instead use `pImpl`:

```
class TestImpl;
class Test
{
public:
  Test();
  ~Test();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<TestImpl> m_;
};
```

and inside your .cpp file, create a `TestImpl` with all of its data right there.

This will hide your implementation details better, and decrease indirection because all of the data for `Test` is now coherently (clumped), if still one step of indirection removed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it allocated on the heap or potentially on the stack? There are reasons to use each approach (e.g. object lifetimes), use the appropriate choice for the situation. I feel like there is no point in doing pointer management if you don't have to; even if you are using smart pointers.

Also, classes like `std::string` internally are usually a pointer to a heap allocated string. So in this case, you'd be doing a heap allocation for a single pointer. Heap allocation is more expensive than stack allocation, and lots of really small allocations will tend to fragment your heap space quickly, making it more difficult (a.k.a. slower) for the allocator to find reasonably sized blocks of contiguous free space.

IMO, consistency in general is good, but consistency for the sake of consistency is rigid and unrealistic.